# Double instance of sentry2 in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, administration, laravel-4

So Sentry2 is awesome,

It has roles, permissions, activation... the list goes on.
So if you want to authenticate the users who use your application this is great.

But what if you want to have multiple user types for your application?

Let's have a simple example, I have an app that I am the administrator of, I run the app through the /admin/.. routes, so I use sentry to authorize that.

But now the app is changing, we are including a "Shopping Cart" module into our app.

We now need to be able to Authorize the users in the shopping cart. they have nothing to do with the users that actually manage the application. so we want them to be in their own table, with their own meta data, login/registration routes etc.

This is where is get's complicated. We basically need two installs of Sentry2, one for the application managers, and one for the clients.

How can we do this?

Comment: Why dont you just use groups?

http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/groups/create

Comment: Because for my administration users I don't care about what their postal address is, but for my shopping cart users I don't give them a "official title" for example. completely different data sets, so I want different tables.

Comment: did you found any solution? same problem here

Answer (score 1):

You could distinguish between users by using groups. You could then store all user's basic data in the users table, and create a second table to contain extra data you need to store for shoppers.

Comment: I've got the same situation as Hailwood here. The problem of your approach is that you can just login to one user at a time. So, if you are testing the shopping cart you would have to logout and login again to go to the admin.

Comment: Same question here. I think this is not a good approach because including this relationship it will change whole functionality of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://help.cartalyst.com/discussions/questions/110-how-to-use-multiple-configurations-of-sentry-in-the-same-laravel-4-app-one-for-public-and-one-for-admin-area

I'm trying to do it but its some confusing.